# Git repos hungs up unexpectedly

Tags: django, git

There is a strange thing.. I can clone small files repos, but when it starts to take some time, it hangs up. Like:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/django/django.git#egg=Django
Obtaining Django from git+https://github.com/django/django.git#egg=Django
Cloning https://github.com/django/django.git to ./virtualenvs/prp/src/django
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Complete output from command /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/django/django.git /home/mamber/virtualenvs/prp/src/django:

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/django/django.git     /home/mamber/virtualenvs/prp/src/django failed with error code 128 in None
Storing complete log in /home/mamber/.pip/pip.log
```

I've tried with some other public repos and getting the same result. 
I also tried just cloning the repo, without virtualenv and pip, same result:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
Cloning into 'django'...
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Maybe there is some timeout config I need to change. I see no traffic in my system monitor while waiting.

I am doing that in a fresh installed Linux Mint, with fresh installed apt-get install git (with no configurations).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see this same problem when cloning without the virtualenv? Might be your totally unrelated to that, e.g. your proxy settings.

Comment: I tried that, just updated my question..

Comment: Sounds like an issue with github's servers. I've had this happen a couple times and waiting 15 minutes always fixes it for me.

Comment: Spike, very unlikely.. I've been trying for 2 days, many times. Didn't solve.

Comment: I'm having this issue now (nearly a year later). Did it fix itself?

Comment: I just realized installing Chromium made it happen. So I fresh installed my Mint Linux and stopped using it =/